# Dynamic form with REST API

Tags: forms, rest

I want to create a REST API which will be used by multiple clients (for now a web page and an Android app). On client side, I need a form which contains (among other data) several comboboxes: Country, Region (these values should be dependent on selected country) and Currency.
In database I store only codes, as I want the values to be translatable on client side.
What is the preferable way to fill the combobox values? So far i considered these options:

1. Call API for each field separately ex. `/countries`, `regions/{countryId}`, `/currencies`.
   This requires multiple calls and recall the regions endpoint every time user changes country.
2. Call API once and get all possible values ex. `/formData`. I think downside of this is that the response might be a bit large.
3. Maybe don't call the API at all, instead store possible values on client side.

I considered the 3rd option the most, because I need to store the translations anyway, but there is need to implement some kind of logic to restrict the regions to given country.
Is there any method that is considered as "the correct" or a good practice?
Or maybe should I consider doing the internationalization of values returned by API on server side?

Comment: what happens when u create an entity? how does the client's know the new translations? So far the cleanest solution is for me number one. You only getting the data u really needed

Comment: I assume that client and server will be updated at the same time, so when I add something new, I should add it to the client(s) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to follow the REST prenciples

> Representational state transfer (REST) is a software architectural style that describes a uniform interface between physically separate components, often across the Internet in a client-server architecture. REST defines four interface constraints:

> - Identification of resources
> - Manipulation of resources
> - Self-descriptive messages and
> - Hypermedia as the engine of application state

*Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer*

The Option number 2 is a no go.

---

So Option 1 or 3 is the right way. You should consider what is more scalable for you.
How often will it be updated? How many languages u want to support?

For simple applications I would prefer option 1 + translations. So the API tells you exactly what it will be accepted.
UI will also not be invalid.

For complex applications I would go with option 3. You should already have some workflows for consistency with Backend and Frontend.

But dont forget to always valide the inputs on the backend side!

---

At the End you are the programmer. It depends and your use cases and what u already have. When your translations are frontend 100% only, why adding another translation service on the backend?